# Application crash when receiving data from Socket.Receive TCP C#

Tags: c#, sockets, serversocket

i have an chat room application that has two parts server and client.
server part can receive data from multi clients. So far so good.
But when one of the client leaves, the software gets an error!

this is server source code:
I commented on the line where the software gets an error !!!

```
Socket _server;
private void StartServer()
{
    _server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    _server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 100010));
    _server.Listen(1);

    while (true) {
        Socket client = _server.Accept();
        Thread rd = new Thread(ReceiveData);
        rd.Start(client);
    }
}

public void ReceiveData(object skt)
{
    Socket socket = (Socket)skt;
    while (true) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int r = socket.Receive(buffer);// when a client leave here get an error !!!
        if (r > 0)
            Console.WriteLine(socket.RemoteEndPoint.Address + ": " + Encoding.Unicode.GetString(b));
    }
}
```

Error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

How can i fix it ?

Comment: And the error message is a secret?

Comment: This is perfectly normal behavior, per the [Socket.Receive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receive?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-socket-receive(system-byte())) documentation. There is nothing to "fix" because it is not broken,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just handle the exception:

```
try
{
    // code that uses the socket
}
catch (SocketException e) when (e.SocketErrorCode is SocketError.ConnectionAborted)
{
    // code to handle the situation gracefully
}
```

Or if you are using an older compiler:

```
try
{
    // code that uses the socket
}
catch (SocketException e)
{
    if(e.SocketErrorCode != SocketError.ConnectionAborted)
    {
        // rethrow the exception
        throw;
    }

    // code to handle the situation gracefully
}
```

Comment: Are you sure no better way ? but thanks :D

Comment: @mahdiwich Well, the only other real alternative that I know of is to periodically ask the socket how many available bytes it has buffered for reading, but that is busy waiting which is much worse than exception handling, not to mention you won't know if the connection has been severed or not.

Comment: @mahdiwich Another note: You should really not be afraid to use exceptions. Other than methods like TryParse() or TryCopyTo(), they are the idiomatic way of coding in C#.